# How do I get rid of a border around an image when I publish a google sheet to the web?

Tags: image, google-sheets, formatting

I have a spreadsheet that I have published to the web. On my spreadsheet there are no borders around my images, but when I go to the published version all my images have black borders around them.

It goes away if I put an image in a selected cell, however I can't find a way to align the image to the complete right and bottom edges of the cell I put it in.

How can I get rid of the border?

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet with this problem?